# Accepting either a string or an integer for a date

Tags: python

How to check whether the parameter I passed in function is integer, string or date in python?

My function can accept either a string or an integer as the date:

```
def check(self, dat1):

    # print(self.path)
    # dat1 = raw_input("data = ")
    print(type(dat1))

    try:
        datetime.datetime.strptime(dat1, '%Y-%m-%d')

    except ValueError:

        try:
            int(dat1)

        except ValueError:
            print("str it is")

        else:

            print(dat1)
            rand1 = random.randint(int(dat1) - (int(dat1) % 7), int(dat1) + (int(dat1) % 7))
            print(rand1)
            return rand1
    else:
        print("date it is")
check(100)
```

I get an error like this when I pass in an integer:

```
    datetime.datetime.strptime(dat1, '%Y-%m-%d')
TypeError: must be string, not int
```

I know there is a question similar but it works for `raw_input()` not for parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument to the `datetime.datetime.strptime()` method *must* be a string. You are passing it an integer instead, and that means a `TypeError` is raised.

Catch that exception too, and not just `ValueError` (which is thrown if you pass in the right type but the string could not be parsed):

```
try:
    datetime.datetime.strptime(dat1, '%Y-%m-%d')
except (ValueError, TypeError):
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `isinstance`

```
>>> my_str = "Foo"
>>> isinstance(my_str, str)
True
>>> my_int = 1234
>>> isinstance(my_int, int)
True
>>> my_date = datetime.date.today()
>>> isinstance(my_date, datetime.date)
True
# Assuming you used "import datetime" at the top of your file
```

You could then use a if-elif structure to raise appropriate exceptions.